# Normalisation - best way to clean duplicate misspelled values in a sql column

Tags: sql

```
+---------+
| Language|
+---------+
|Spanish  | 
|spanish  | 
|venezla  | 
|venezuala| 
|irish    | 
|Irish    |
+---------+
```

Best approach for normalising data in a sql column? I was thinking of converting to lower case and then using multiple replace functions. Is this the only way? Any insight appreciated thanks :)

Comment: Load the data into a spreadsheet and manually input the correct names.  Then re-import into the database.

Comment: Why are sql coders so snarky. I don't have table access dude

Comment: If you don't have access to the table, then how are you going to clean it up?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using?

Comment: @skiventist . . . I haven't the faintest idea what you are calling snarky.  That is the solution that I have used on multiple occasions to fix this type of problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in sql to do it my friend, it totally depends on the scenario and how you want to utilize it.

Looking at the above ask, you can use LOWER function and then extract the DISTINCT values to give unique values instead of putting multiple REPLACE functions every time you see a new mismatched value.

Or you can delete duplicate values by applying ROW_NUMBER and LOWER function if you want to play around with 1 table only.

Let me know your feedback and i can revert with more inputs.